# How to convert Log4j.xml to Log4j2.properties (Rewrite Polici)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j2

i want to use `Rewrite Policy` for some condition in logging like masking, and then I found the solution but in `log4j2.xml`, however we use `log4j2.properties` for base config, I already try to config but the rewrite still not working.

here other config compare to my config

Other Config :

```
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="LOG_DIR">/logs</Property>
  </Properties>

  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile
      name="rollingFile"
      fileName="D:/logs/omnichannel/application.log"
      filePattern="D:/logs/omnichannel/application.%i.log.gz"
      ignoreExceptions="false">
      <PatternLayout>
          <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
          <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5">
        <Delete basePath="D:/logs/" maxDepth="2">
          <IfFileName glob="*/app-*.log.gz" />
          <IfLastModified age="P30D" />
        </Delete>
      </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
     <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT" ignoreExceptions="false">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
    </Console>
    <Rewrite name="Rewrite">
      <LogInterceptor />
      <AppenderRef ref="rollingFile"/>
    </Rewrite>
  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="Rewrite"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

And my config here :

```
status = warn
name= PropertiesConfig

# Give directory path where log files should get stored
property.basePath = D://logs//

appenders = rolling, console, Rewrite 

appender.Rewrite.type = Rewrite
appender.Rewrite.name = Rewrite
appender.Rewrite.layout.type = LogInterceptor
appender.Rewrite.layout.RewriteAppender = fileLogger

# ConsoleAppender will print logs on console
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = consoleLogger
appender.console.target = SYSTEM_OUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
# Specify the pattern of the logs
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %highlight{[%-5level]}{TRACE=magenta} %mask %logger{36}.%M(%L) : %msg%n%throwable
appender.console.layout.disableAnsi=false

# RollingFileAppender will print logs in file which can be rotated based on time or size
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = fileLogger
appender.rolling.fileName = ${basePath}${hostName}.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${basePath}${hostName}_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern =  %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] [%-5level] %logger{36}.%M(%L) : %msg%n%throwable
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies

# Rotate log file each day and keep 30 days worth
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.action.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.action.basePath = ${basePath}
appender.rolling.strategy.action.maxDepth = 1
appender.rolling.strategy.action.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified
appender.rolling.strategy.fileIndex = nomax

# For hibernate tracing query parameter, make this default not opened
#loggers = application, hibernate
loggers = application, httpclient, Client


# Mention package name here. Classes in this package or sub packages will use ConsoleAppender and RollingFileAppender for logging         
logger.application.name = com.project
logger.application.level = info
logger.application.appenderRefs = rolling
logger.application.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger

logger.httpclient.name = org.apache.http
logger.httpclient.level = info
logger.httpclient.appenderRefs = rolling
logger.httpclient.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger

logger.Client.name = com.sun.jersey.api
logger.Client.level = info
logger.Client.appenderRefs = rolling
logger.Client.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger

# For hibernate tracing query parameter, make this default not opened
#logger.hibernate.name = org.hibernate.type
#logger.hibernate.level = trace
#Logger.hibernate.Additivity = false

# Configure root logger for logging error logs in classes which are in package other than above specified package
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRefs = Rewrite
rootLogger.appenderRef.Rewrite.ref = Rewrite
```

my function rewrite :

```
@Plugin(name = "LogInterceptor", category = "Core", elementType = "rewritePolicy", printObject = true)
public class LoggingMaskingConverter implements RewritePolicy {
    
    protected static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(LoggingMaskingConverter.class);

    private static final List<String> loggingSetting = Arrays.asList("pin,password".split(","));
    
    private static final String loggingMasking = "1";
    
    private static final List<String> excludePath = Collections.emptyList();
    
    private static final String STR_BODY = "body=[";
    
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    
     @PluginFactory
     public static LoggingMaskingConverter createPolicy() {
         return new LoggingMaskingConverter();
     }
     
     @Override
     public LogEvent rewrite(LogEvent event) {
         if (event.getLoggerName().contains("com.project")) {
             
             Message outputMessage = logInfoMasking(event.getMessage());

             return new Log4jLogEvent.Builder(event).setMessage(outputMessage).build();
         } else {
             return new Log4jLogEvent.Builder(event).build();
         }
        
     }
     
     public Message logInfoMasking(Message message) {
         StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
         try {
             String body = message.getFormattedMessage();
             ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
             if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(loggingMasking) && loggingMasking.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                 if (body != null) {
                     Collection<String> whitelist = loggingSetting;
                     Collection<String> excludeKeys = excludePath;
                     JsonMasker masker = new JsonMasker(whitelist, excludeKeys);
                        
                     JsonNode jsonNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(body);
                     JsonNode masked =  masker.mask(jsonNode);
                     stringBuilder.append(STR_BODY + masked.toString() + "]");
                 }
             } else {
                 String json = ow.writeValueAsString(body);
                 stringBuilder.append(STR_BODY + json + "]");
             }
                
         } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
             log.error(e, e);
         }
         return new ObjectMessage(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
}
```

i spend my time around one day to solve this. until this day. the rewrite still not working in logs file but in my function rewrite going well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general format to configure a Log4j2 component via properties is:

```
<parent_component_prefix>.<arbitrary_id>.type = ComponentType
<parent_component_prefix>.<arbitrary_id>.property1 = value1
...
```

So in your case you need:

```
appender.$0.type = Rewrite
appender.$0.name = Rewrite

appender.$0.$1.type = LogInterceptor

appender.$0.$2.type = AppenderRef
appender.$0.$2.ref = fileLogger
```

Comment: broo, you save my day.. thanks for the answer, this solved my problem.. great